# DataFrame. TypeError: 'numpy.int64' inside a FOR loop in Data

Tags: python, pandas

Goal is to create a function able to de-cumulate the column of table.
For example:

```py
data_matrix = {'x0': [0, 2, 0],

'x1':[2, 3, 1],

'x3':[4, 4, 1],

'x4':[6, 5, 1]}

data_mtrice = pd.DataFrame(data_matrix)
data_matrice = data_mtrice.T
```

That produces:

```
data_matrice.head()
```

Out[30]:

```
    0  1  2

x0  0  2  0

x1  2  3  1

x3  4  4  1

x4  6  5  1
```

Each line is a cumulative sum. For example, 0+2= 2 then 0+2+2 = 4 then 0+2+2+2 = 6.
I am looking for a function to de-cumulate.
I tried to write:

```py
import pandas as pd
def decumule(tableau):

    decu_table = np.zeros(tableau.shape)
    for ligne, element in enumerate(tableau.iloc()):
        print("ligne = ",ligne)
        for colon, elem in enumerate(tableau.iloc[ligne]):
            if ligne > 0:
                print("colonn",colon)
                decu_table.iloc[[ligne, colon]] = tableau.iloc[[ligne, colon]] - tableau.iloc[[ligne - 1, colon]]
            else:
                 decu_table.iloc[[ligne, colon]] = tableau.iloc[[ligne, colon]]
    return decu_table

tentative = data_matrice.apply(lambda tableau: decumule(tableau))
```

That produces:

```
for colon, elem in enumerate(tableau.iloc[ligne]):

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

Do you have any idea what can go wrong?

Regards,
Atapalou

Answer (score 2):

There are tree problems with your code.

The first is with `tentative = data_matrice.apply(lambda tableau: decumule(tableau))`, your function `decumule` expects a dataframe as input, when you call `apply` though the function is applied one row at a time so it gets only a row as input. This is easily fixable by just changing it to `tentative = decumule(data_matrix)`.

The second problem is with the indexing in the `.iloc`, if you call `df.iloc[[1, 2]]` you get full rows number 1 and 2. To get the element at index (1, 2) instead you need `df.iloc[1, 2]`.

The third (and simplest) is that `decu_table` is created as a numpy ndarray which does not support `.iloc`. To fix this just convert it to a pandas dataframe

Fixing both problems you get:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_matrix = {"x0": [0, 2, 0], "x1": [2, 3, 1], "x3": [4, 4, 1], "x4": [6, 5, 1]}

data_matrix = pd.DataFrame(data_matrix)
data_matrix = data_matrix.T


def decumule(tableau):
    decu_table = pd.DataFrame(
        np.zeros(tableau.shape), columns=tableau.columns, index=tableau.index
    )
    for ligne, element in enumerate(tableau.iloc()):
        print("ligne = ", ligne)
        for colon, elem in enumerate(tableau.iloc[ligne]):
            if ligne > 0:
                print("colonn", colon)
                decu_table.iloc[ligne, colon] = (
                    tableau.iloc[ligne, colon] - tableau.iloc[ligne - 1, colon]
                )
            else:
                decu_table.iloc[ligne, colon] = tableau.iloc[ligne, colon]
    return decu_table


tentative = decumule(data_matrix)
```

That produces:

```
     0    1    2
0  0.0  2.0  0.0
1  2.0  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  0.0
3  2.0  1.0  0.0
```

Just as an additional note you are performing the calculations one cell at a time. This can be simplified by calculating one row at a time like this:

```py
def decumule(tableau):
    decu_table = pd.DataFrame(
        np.zeros(tableau.shape), columns=tableau.columns, index=tableau.index
    )
    for ligne, element in enumerate(tableau.iloc()):
        print("ligne = ", ligne)
        if ligne > 0:
            decu_table.iloc[ligne] = tableau.iloc[ligne] - tableau.iloc[ligne - 1]
        else:
            decu_table.iloc[ligne] = tableau.iloc[ligne]
    return decu_table
```

Wich gives the same result as the previous but is faster

Answer (score 1):

De-cumulation is commonly referred to as an array `diff` operation. pandas also can perform `diff`s on its base objects as well, so you can get your desired result like so:

```py
print(
    data_matrice.diff()
)
      0    1    2
x0  NaN  NaN  NaN
x1  2.0  1.0  1.0
x3  2.0  1.0  0.0
x4  2.0  1.0  0.0
```

Then if you want those `NaN` values in the top row to match the original values from `data_matrice` you can add in a call to `.fillna`

```py
print(
    data_matrice.diff().fillna(data_matrice.iloc[0])
)
      0    1    2
x0  0.0  2.0  0.0
x1  2.0  1.0  1.0
x3  2.0  1.0  0.0
x4  2.0  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

By making a detour through numpy, another solution is:

```
def decumule(tableau):
    decu_table = pd.DataFrame(
        np.zeros(tableau.shape), columns=tableau.columns, index=tableau.index
    )
    for ligne, element in enumerate(tableau.iloc()):
        print("ligne = ", ligne)
        if ligne > 0:
            decu_table.iloc[ligne] = tableau.iloc[ligne] - tableau.iloc[ligne - 1]
        else:
            decu_table.iloc[ligne] = tableau.iloc[ligne]
    return pd.DataFrame(decu_table)
```